# help using xargs to pass mulitiple filenames to shell script

Tags: shell, unix

Can someone show me to use xargs properly? Or if not xargs, what unix command should I use?

I basically want to input more than (1) file name for input `<localfile>`, third input parameter.

For example:

```
1. use `find` to get list of files
2. use each filename as input to shell script
```

Usage of shell script:

```
test.sh <localdir> <localfile> <projectname>
```

My attempt, but not working:

```
find /share1/test -name '*.dat' | xargs ./test.sh /staging/data/project/ '{}' projectZ \;
```

**Edit:**
After some input from everybody and trying `-exec`, I am finding that my `<localfile>` filename input with `find` is also giving me the full path. `/path/filename.dat` instead of `filename.dat`. Is there a way to get the basename from `find`? I think this will have to be a separate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use [`find -exec`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/find/) here:

```
% find /share1/test -name '*.dat' -exec ./test.sh /staging/data/project/ {} projectZ \;
```

This will invoke `./test.sh` with your three arguments once for each `.dat` file under `/share1/test`.

[`xargs`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xargs/) would pack up all of these filenames and pass them into one invocation of `./test.sh`, which doesn't look like your desired behaviour.

Comment: its close. i'm still having problems running it. what i think is happening is find is now giving me the file name and the path `/path/filename.dat` and I just need the basename only.

Comment: @jdamae: If `./test.sh` requires basenames, then it should be changed to call [`basename`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/basename/). You may be able to do `-exec ./test.sh /staging/data/project/ $(basename {}) projectZ \;` otherwise (untested).

Comment: this basically answers my question. thank you. i think i have to post another question on extracting only the basename of the output from find.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to execute the shell script for each file (as opposed to execute in only once on the whole list of files), you may want to use `find -exec`:

```
find /share1/test -name '*.dat' -exec ./test.sh /staging/data/project/ '{}' projectZ \;
```

Remember:

- `find -exec` is for when you want to run a command on *one* file, for each file.
- `xargs` instead runs a command only *once*, using *all* the files as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying use between the each cmd.

Comment: @jdamae: this is not forced behavior of `xargs`,  I'm writing a proper answer with the correct `xargs` options.

Answer (score 2):

xargs stuffs as many files as it can onto the end of the command line.
Do you want to execute the script on one file at a time or all files?  For one at a time, use file's exec, which it looks like you're already using the syntax for, and which xargs doesn't use:

```
find /share1/test -name '*.dat' -exec ./test.sh /staging/data/project/ '{}' projectZ \;
```

Comment: execute one at a time. thanks for your reply. I edited my question as I started to test `exec`.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` does not have to combine arguments, it's just the default behavior.  this properly uses `xargs`, to execute the commands, as intended.

```
find /share1/test -name '*.dat' -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' ./test.sh /staging/data/project/ '{}' projectZ
```

When piping `find` to `xargs`, NULL termination is usually preferred, I recommend appending the `-print0` option to `find`.  After which you must add `-0` to `xargs`, so it will expect NULL terminated arguments.  This ensures proper handling of filenames.  It's not POSIX proper, but considered well supported.  You can always drop the NULL terminating options, if your commands lack support.

Remeber while `find`'s purpose is finding files, `xargs` is much more generic.  I often use `xargs` to process non-filename arguments.